# Trying to make Masonry-Layout work in Safari with imagesLoaded

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5, imagesloaded

I successfully implemented a Masonry-Gallery for a WordPress website by using Bootstrap 5 in combination with 'Masonry-Layout'.
It works all fine except in Safari, where the layout usually breaks, a known problem and the solution is supposed to be 'imagesLoaded'.
I tried a lot, but I just don't manage to add the needed classes at the right place(s).
The code as far as I got, see below. Anybody who can help?

```
<div class="row grid" id="gallery-masonry" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
    
<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery');
$size = 'large';
    
if( $images ): ?>       
        <?php foreach( $images as $image_id ): ?>
    
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">            
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="card rounded-0" >  

    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size, "", ["class" => "card-img-top rounded-0","alt"=>""]); ?>

    </div>
</div>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
  
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<!--Masonry-Layout-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" integrity="sha384-GNFwBvfVxBkLMJpYMOABq3c+d3KnQxudP/mGPkzpZSTYykLBNsZEnG2D9G/X/+7D" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>


<!--ImagesLoaded-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@5/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<!--Script ImagesLoaded-->
<script>
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Masonry after all images have loaded
  $grid.masonry({
    // options...
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the output of the `<img>` tag contain `width` and `height` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my post regarding adding a Masonry to a Wordpress Site.

https://www.customfitwebdesign.com/how-to-add-masonry-layout-in-wordpress/

Note: Masonry is actually built into the core of WordPress ( wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js ). This WordPress version of Masonry also includes ImagesLoaded (imagesloaded.min.js).